# variable value not being increased prior to the ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a url string being compiled based on existing PHP array values.
The URL is fine however after each time the AJAX call is made I want the variable last
increased by 100.
The console log is showing the correct value yet the URL string has NULL after the offset value
Here is the URL string shown in console log

```
basictest.php?base=accountancy-jobs&cat=accountancy&kw=&loc=London&distance=10&cattitle=Accountancy&offset=200NULL
```

The value is being increased yet its adding NULL after it for some reason

Here is my code

```
let last = 100;
let vars = '<?php foreach($passedVars as $vars=>$key){ if($vars == 'base'){ echo $vars.'='.$key;$pv++;} if($pv < $pvcount){ echo '&'.$vars.'='.$key;$pv++;} else {echo '&'.$vars.'='.$key;}}?><?php echo "&offset=100";?>'; 
 
$('#next').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
    vars = '<?php foreach($passedVars as $vars=>$key){ if($vars == 'base'){ echo $vars.'='.$key;$pv++;} if($pv < $pvcount){ echo '&'.$vars.'='.$key;$pv++;} else {echo '&'.$vars.'='.$key;}}?><?php echo "&offset=";?>'+last;
   $.ajax({
                   dataType: 'html',
                   url: 'basictest.php?'+vars,
                   type: 'get',
                   success: function(html)
                   {
                       $("#more").append(html);
                       last += 100;
                       console.log(html);
                       console.log(last);
                   }
           });
       });
```

Comment: _"Here is the URL string shown in console log"_ - by which exact console.log statement - one you did not actually show us? Or are you talking about `console.log(html)`? `html` is what you responded with from the server side, but you didn't actually show us any of that.

Comment: Also please use a URL searchParams object instead of that horrible mess you have in the php

Comment: This is why I'm struggling.. completely new to jquery

Comment: And yes the html response contains the REQUEST_URI as I wanted to make sure it was formatted correctly

Answer (score 1):

Do not use PHP because you are using AJAX so the vars are not updated since you are not supposed to reload the page...

Use URL and [URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to update the  offset and $.get to get a new page

```js
let last = 0;
let url = new URL(`https://yourserver.com/basictest.php?base=accountancy-jobs&cat=accountancy&kw=&loc=London&distance=10&cattitle=Accountancy&offset=0`)

$('#next').on('click', (e) => {
  url.searchParams.set('offset',last)
console.log(url.toString())
//  $.get(url.toString(), (html) => {
//    $("#more").append(html);
    last += 100;
//  }));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to introduce your PHP array into Javascript using [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to add `last` to `offset` and [param](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) `$.param(vars)` to add the query string to the URL.

```php
$passedVars = array(
    'base' => 'accountancy-jobs',
    'cat' => 'accountancy',
    'kw' => '',
    'loc' => 'London',
    'distance' => '10',
    'cattitle' => 'Accountancy',
    'offset' => '200'
);
```

```html
<button id="next">Next</button>
<div id="more"></div>
```

```js
let last = 100;
let vars = <?php echo json_encode($passedVars)?>; 
 
$('#next').click(function(e){
    vars['offset'] = parseInt(vars['offset']) + last;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'basictest.php?' + $.param(vars),
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'get'
    }).done(function(html){
        $("#more").append(html);
        console.log(html);
        console.log(vars['offset']);
    });

    return false;
});
```